# Unable to compile BACnet code

Tags: dynamic-c

I'm trying to run some BACnet code on the Rabbit Processor and it is throwing the following errors:

```
line  200 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'STDINT.H' cannot be found.            
line  201 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'CONFIG.H' cannot be found.            
line  202 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'VERSION.H' cannot be found.           
line  204 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'KEY.H' cannot be found.               
line  205 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'KEYLIST.C' cannot be found.           
line  206 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'INDTEXT.C' cannot be found.           
line  207 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'FIFO.C' cannot be found.              
line  208 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'RINGBUF.C' cannot be found.           
line  209 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'FILENAME.C' cannot be found.          
line  210 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'MEMCOPY.C' cannot be found.           
line  211 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'CRC.C' cannot be found.               
line  213 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'BACENUM.H' cannot be found.           
line  214 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'BACDEF.H' cannot be found.            
line  215 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'BACSTRUCTS.H' cannot be found.        
line  217 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'BACSTR.C' cannot be found.            
line  218 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'BITS.C' cannot be found.              
line  219 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'BACINT.C' cannot be found.            
line  220 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'BACREAL.C' cannot be found.           
line  221 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'DATETIME.C' cannot be found.          
line  223 : ERROR BACNET.LIB   : 'TXBUF.C' cannot be found.
```

The problem is that all the ".c" files are present in the same directory and I have also mentioned the include path in the project options. Is there some other setting that I need to take care of? Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lib.dir file in the dynamic c directory needs to have the bacnet folders added to it. The arc, demo\handlers and demo\objects folders will need to bá added.